# I'm unable to install headless CMS in sitecore 10.2 Docker Setup?

Tags: jss, installation, docker, container

Encountering error:

```
invalid from flag value headless_image: pull access denied for headless_image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Using Image: `scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-headless-services-xm1-assets:20.0.2-1809`

For Windows Docker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen due to the Docker Desktop configuring to `Compose V2` mode.

Open up Docker Desktop, go to `Settings` and Uncheck `Use Docker Compose V2`.

[image]

Refer to [this](https://errorcotidianam.blog/2021/09/14/sitecore-docker-common-issues-on-installation/) document for common docker installation issues.

Hope this helps.